# MySQL Update using input from JTable not working

Tags: java, mysql

This is the code that works and update my database in phpmyadmin:

```
 for (int i=0; i<rowno; i++){
            Object obj1 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i,0);
            String itm = obj1.toString();
            System.out.println(itm);
            Object obj2 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1);
            String qty = obj2.toString();
            System.out.println(qty);
            Object obj3 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);
            String rt = obj3.toString();
            System.out.println(rt);
            Object obj4 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
            String total = obj4.toString();
            System.out.println(total);
            Query("INSERT INTO Detail (OrderNumber, Items, Quantity, Rate, Total) VALUES ("+orderno.getText()+",'Item',"+qty+","+rt+","+total+")");
     }
```

Explanation: as you can see I am not retrieving data and passing it to Items, I have merely hard-coded the string Item. This is to show that the data from qty, rt and total are being updated fine.

HOWEVER when I try to pass value from itm (obj 1 to String) as shown below:

```
for (int i=0; i<rowno; i++){
            Object obj1 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i,0);
            String itm = obj1.toString();
            System.out.println(itm);
            Object obj2 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1);
            String qty = obj2.toString();
            System.out.println(qty);
            Object obj3 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);
            String rt = obj3.toString();
            System.out.println(rt);
            Object obj4 = orders.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
            String total = obj4.toString();
            System.out.println(total);
            Query("INSERT INTO Detail (OrderNumber, Items, Quantity, Rate, Total) VALUES ("+orderno.getText()+","+itm+","+qty+","+rt+","+total+")");

     }
```

It gives me this SQLExeption:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Product1' in 'field list'

'Product1' being the first row first column of my JTable.

Help Needed.

Answer (score 0):

This page actually helped me solved the issue:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-the-hash1054-unknown-column-error-occurs-in-mysql-and-how-to-fix-it

The trouble was that unlike the other data I was inserting in the table, Item was the only VARCHAR.
Therefore String which implies single quote are in order:

Query("INSERT INTO Detail (OrderNumber, Items, Quantity, Rate, Total) VALUES ("+orderno.getText()+",'"+itm+"',"+qty+","+rt+","+total+")");